# History and philosophy of Krishna sects

Tags: krishna, sects

Krishna sects seemed to have risen in medieval period. What caused the sects to rise? Name of the sects and their beliefs can be stated in the answer.  ( I know about Gaudiya tradition and Vallabha sect to some extent but one can include them as well in answers, I am more looking for sects like Radha-pranami etc..).

Comment: Krishna sects are older than medeival period. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megasthenes%27_Herakles  and also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliodorus_pillar

Comment: There is an opinion that Herakles is derived from Sanskrit word Harikulesa.

Comment: @LazyLubber interesting information.